# outlook web access galfind command returns only 100 records

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-web-app

I am trying to retrieve a list of all users using outlook web access.

Using Galfind command like https://server/?Cmd=galFind&cy=workplace

i can retrieve only 100 records... (i think its fixed in outlook)

Is there any way i can retrieve more than 100 records..

Note: I want to query Global Address List in Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `System.DirectoryServices` namepsace, specifically the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` class; it's pretty straightforward to query AD users using that, and you get a rich query syntax.  galfind is only really intended to be used by OWA's client-side UI; I don't think Microsoft ever really expected people to use it directly.